# ng-src throws a 404 because my img is not set yet

Tags: angularjs

I have a div containing an image (for a preview), shown only when an image src is set.
My problem is I get a 404, because at the start there's no image set.

```
<div ng-show="imgSrc" class="preview">
    <div class="menu">
        <a ng-click="imgSrc = false" class="btn btn-primary">
             <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Close</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ imgSrc }}">
             <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download</a>
    <img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}" /> /* <--------------------- here */
</div>
```

Is it a good way to do that ? or should I remove image tag, and append it when an img is set ? in this case, how can I append elements ?

Comment: Where is imgSrc defined? If your

Comment: Where is imgSrc defined and what is the scope of the html?

Answer (score 2):

The 404 means the image does not exist on the server, it does not mean the `imgSrc` is not defined.

If you want to hide the element until the `imgSrc` is defined, use the `nh-show` directive, like you are already using. Also, make sure `imgSrc` doesn't have a default value.

If you want to check if the image exists on the server before showing it on the UI, you will have to do an ajax request to that URL and check the returned response.

### Edit

Also `ng-click="imgSrc = false"` should be `ng-click="imgSrc = ''"`.

Comment: The img it's trying to load is : http://localhost:9000/false, that's why it throws 404

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid URL for an image. Are you defining any default value for `imgSrc` ?

Comment: Yep, that's it. I noticed the `imgSrc = false` in the `ng-click` but that would make it the default value.

Answer (score 1):

OK I understand the reason of 404. My imgSrc variable was initialized to false, so it was trying to load :

```
http://localhost:9000/false
```

A simple imgSrc = '' instead fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting `imgSrc` to `false` when you click the close link, set it to the empty string. This will still cause `ng-show` to hide it correctly, but not result in the browser trying to fetch `http://localhost:9000/false`.

e.g. change your markup to:

```
    <div ng-show="imgSrc" class="preview">
        <div class="menu"> 
            <a ng-click="imgSrc = ''" class="btn btn-primary">
             <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Close</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ imgSrc }}" target="_blank">
             <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download</a>

            <img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
```

See a [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u36fvyf5/).

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive for image load like this

**Directive :**

```
app.directive('imageonload', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                alert('image is loaded');
                 $rootScope.$broadcast('updateContent');
            });
        }
    };
});
HTML :
<div ng-show="isImage" class="preview">
    <div class="menu">
        <a ng-click="imgSrc = false" class="btn btn-primary">
             <i class="fa fa-times"></i>Close</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ imgSrc }}">
             <i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download</a>
    <img ng-src="{{ imgSrc }}" imageonload /> /* <--------------------- here */
</div>
```

contoller :

```
$scope.$on('updateContent', function () {
        console.log('receive');
        $scope.isImage = true;
    });
```